# JavaScript ran on page, but at the end deleted its own DOM node. How do I test it did something?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

A scenario,

I have a script element in the DOM

This script did "things" on the page, then it **deleted itself**

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="the-javascript">
(function (d){

    var ...,
        script = d.getElementById('the-javascript'),
        ...;

    // lotsa code !!

    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);

}(document));
</script>
```

This was an Anonymous IIFE (Immediately invoked function execution)
How do I know that JavaScript was executed on the page. Stuck in a scenario in which I must find that.

Anything other than `view-source`?

EDIT:

Let me clarify this. Someone please explain the downvote
I am running a test case, that needs to find if JavaScript ran on the page
I know the use of Developer Tools. Duh !
The `code` was in a `script` tag and the code deleted the `script` tag
The code was anonymous, so no globals that I can check in console, or wherever
I have to find if that JavaScript created any DOM elements, without using `view-source`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @pktangyue, I can't modify the script. Somebody else's DOM

Comment: @OmShankar: You really need to provide more detail. Someone else's DOM?

Comment: @j08691, My question in one line would be - "How do I find that a JavaScript code has been executed on a page, if that code deleted itself". Its not my page, so I am not writing the script to use `console.log`

Comment: If it's been deleted, then you can't find it.

Comment: @OmShankar the code didn't delete itself, see my answer

Comment: Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: @Christophe Tags are not deleted. That's not how the DOM works. Tags are markup that become DOM nodes, which can be deleted, so a script can delete itself in the sense that it removes its DOM node from the DOM..

Comment: @thesystem right :-) I'll update my answer. My point was that the code and the node are two different things.

Comment: @Christophe, modifying the question's code for you, for clarity

Comment: @OmShankar: *"I have to find if that JavaScript created any DOM elements"* So is this your *actual* question? For example, if the script just did `var foo;` in the IIFE, you wouldn't care?

Comment: @thesystem, sort of yes. But it would be nice and awesome, if I could also prove that `var foo;` or may be if `Array.prototype` was changed.

Comment: @OmShankar: Alright, now we're narrowing it down. First, if there were no visible side-effects produced by the script, then no, there really wouldn't be any way to know of its presence unless perhaps you made an XHR request for the same page, and analyzed its content. But if there were side effects, then you'd be able to search for them assuming you can compare the state of the DOM before and after the supposed script. If you are interested in specific things like changes to `Array.prototype`, and if you know the default methods, then you could search for additions.

Comment: -1 as long as you don't want to listen and understand the difference between a script (JavaScript) and a script element (html) you're wasting people's time

Comment: @thesystem, yup, so it boils down to the fact that I can simply say **no** to such a requirement to my tester. Coz, 1 - DOM comparison? no way!! and 2 - I don't want guess what objects it modified. I don't know if it was an `Array` :)

Comment: @Christophe, why don't you get that. I clearly know the difference. Still I would request you to keep ur -1 if you want to think the other way. PS - kindly read comments to get an idea if OP is clear of his own questions!

Comment: @OmShankar: Yeah, it would be a massive undertaking to explore all possible side-effects, and you'd still never know if anything actually ran. So "no" is probably your safest answer.

Comment: @Christophe, `JavaScript` is code that runs in a browser. `JavaScript` can delete a `DOM` element. By the word **itself**, I mean the `DOM` element which was holding the `JavaScript` code. Want to prove that even if the `DOM` **element** (as u say) was deleted, THE SCRIPT CODE RAN. So its ur point only, the **difference**, that in a way I want to prove. Can't be more clear than this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"My question in one line would be - "How do I find that a JavaScript code has been executed on a page, if that code deleted itself"."*

If the script deleted itself from the DOM, it *can't* be found... because it isn't there... because it was deleted.

---

To address the updated question and comments, aside from making an XHR request for the page and analyzing the content received, there's not really any way to safely detect if a script ran and then deleted itself.

You could search for side-effects of the code, but the number of possibilities is really too great, and it could be that the script had no visible side-effect.

Comment: See the code in the question, the script didn't delete itself!

Comment: "It" can't be found. But "it" has been executed. I need to find and prove this to my test case. For example, if there was an `alert`, I could have assumed that there was a JavaScript. But it might have done other things which I don't know. like huge DOM modification

Comment: @Christophe, I can't see how it did not delete itself? However, I am modifying the 2 codes as inline `script` so its more clear to you

Comment: @Christophe: Yes, it deleted itself. It selected its DOM representation by ID, and removed the found node. This doesn't mean that the external resource is deleted, or that the effect of the code having run is undone, but the script is most certainly deleted, and as such, can't be found.

Comment: @OmShankar again, please understand that the script and the node that loaded it are two different things.

Comment: @Christophe: We can have different ideas about what the script is. If you mean the syntax in a text file, that's one thing. But it's clear from the question that OP is referring to the `script` element, which was being removed by the very code that the script element executed. If it wasn't removed, OP would be able to use that element to retrieve the code.

Comment: @Christophe. If I don't understand the difference, I wouldn't ask this question. Coz, I wouldn't get in such a scenario. Can't you get that?? `script` is code, its `JavaScript`. `JavaScript` can modify the `DOM`.  Come on! Its StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Browsers like Chrome or IE have developer tools that tell you (almost) everything about your page. Just activate the tools and watch your page load.

If you want to know what the script does, what you can also do is just navigate to its address: `http://theirSite/main.js`

Note: the script didn't delete itself, it just deleted the node that loaded it.